# c++ function template specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Given this code:

```
class X
{
public:
    template< typename T >
    void func( const T & v );
};

template<>
void X::func< int >( const int & v )
{
}

template<>
void X::func< char * >( const char * & v )       // 16
{
}
```

When I compile it I get the following error.

```
test.cpp:16: error: template-id 'func<char*>' for 'void X::func(const char*&)' does not match any template declaration
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: If you are not planning to implement `template<typename T> void X::func (const T & t) { ... }`, you can just use a member function overloaded for `int` and `char*` parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you face this error is because you write `const` before the type. Although this is common practise, it is not conducive to understanding how const/volatile-qualifiers (cv-qualifier) work.

In this case `const T` when `T` is `char*` doesn't mean `const char*`. It rather means `char* const` because `T` is `char*` and no matter which side of `T` you put `const` it behaves as if `const` is on the right of `T`, that is, the pointer itself that is going to be const not the type pointed too.

It is easy to avoid this type of confusion if you make it a rule to always put `const` or `volatile` on the right of the type. For example, it makes it straightforward to mentally expand `T const` when `T` is `char*` to `char* const`.

This is the reason in boost sources you see cv-qualifiers after the type, not before.

Answer (score 7):

If you change the declaration:

```
template<> void X::func< char * >( const char * & v )
```

to:

```
template<> void X::func< char * >( char * const & v )
```

This would work perfectly fine. Why does it happen? Because while `const sometype` is perfectly acceptable, it's only an alternative notation for `sometype const`. So, your const modifier is not applied to the basic type (`char`), but to the pointer, making "constant pointer to non-constant char" a valid type. If that's not what you want, you'll have to correct your basic template.

Finally, here's some interesting reading for you about [why overloading templates is generally better than specializing them](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Comment: Wow, really great description.

Answer (score 4):

Move `const` before `&`

```
template<> 
void X::func< char * >( char * const & v ) 
{ 
}
```